# Google Indexing [ Kind of Facebook Profile Page, but for Subdomains]

Tags: reactjs, seo, google-search

Assume, i have a  (React SPA + Node based) SAAS product on the domain [www.carpenter.com](http://www.carpenter.com).

Whever, a user sign-ups up,  we collect basic Info like Area of Sevice, zipcode, pricing and we genrate an Appointment link for the carpenter ( eg - [www.username.carpenter.com](http://www.username.carpenter.com))

My question is:

1. Will this domain be Indexable on Google? should i submit a new(updated) robots.txt, everytime a user signs up ?
2. How do i bring this link up first in Google  results when a customer searches  "Username carpenter".

At first glance, this seems to be like facebook Profile page implementation.

How do i provide google the data that is structred inside our DB?

Apologize for asking a broad questions. But i'd like to have maxium inputs on this as possible.

Any pointers / Referrences would be  appreciated!

Thanks

Converitng SPA to SSR seesm to be solution, but i'd like to know will Google index data in my Databse and point to specific profile page like facebook/twitter does?

Also, seems goole has started rending AJAX applicaitons. In that case, should move from Subdomain to  domain.com/username way?

As per my understanding, every subdomain based websites are treated as new sites by google.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.